# XSLT multi level grouping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Thanks in advance for your time. I tried and searched for several solutions but to no avail yet.

I want to print out tickets. Let's say 4 of them fit on one page. But one  may contain more or less than 4 tickets. I want to group all tickets into groups of 4 but with my current translation i get gaps on the pages. I managed to get it to work if I stay within one , it's the multiple  that's making my head hurt atm.

Input

```
<Event>
<Registrations>
    <EventRegistration>
        <Participants>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 1</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 2</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 3</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 4</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 5</Name>
            </Participant>
        </Participants>
    </EventRegistration>
    <EventRegistration>
        <Participants>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 6</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 7</Name>
            </Participant>
            <Participant>
                <Name>Ticket 8</Name>
            </Participant>
        </Participants>
    </EventRegistration>
</Registrations>
```

With current transformation (broke down to the bare minimum)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="participants" match="Participant" use="'all'" />
<xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="4" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <pages>
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="key('participants', 'all')[(position() mod $groupSize) = 1]" mode="multi"/>-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('participants', 'all')" mode="copy"/>
            <!--<xsl:for-each select="key('participants', 'all')[(position() mod $groupSize) = 1]">-->
                <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="multi"/>-->
            <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
        </pages>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="PageNumber" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".[(position() mod $groupSize) = 1]" mode="multi">
        <xsl:with-param name="PageNumber" select="$PageNumber"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!--Page-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="multi">
    <xsl:param name="PageNumber" />
    <page key="{$PageNumber}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $groupSize]" mode="item">
            <xsl:with-param name="PageNumber" select="$PageNumber"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </page>
</xsl:template>
<!--Tickets-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:param name="PageNumber"/>
    <ticket key="{$PageNumber}-{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </ticket>
</xsl:template>
```

Gives result

```
<document>
<pages>
    <page key="1">
        <ticket key="1-1">Ticket 1</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-2">Ticket 2</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-3">Ticket 3</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-4">Ticket 4</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="2">
        <ticket key="2-1">Ticket 2</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-2">Ticket 3</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-3">Ticket 4</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-4">Ticket 5</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="3">
        <ticket key="3-1">Ticket 3</ticket>
        <ticket key="3-2">Ticket 4</ticket>
        <ticket key="3-3">Ticket 5</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="4">
        <ticket key="4-1">Ticket 4</ticket>
        <ticket key="4-2">Ticket 5</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="5">
        <ticket key="5-1">Ticket 5</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="6">
        <ticket key="6-1">Ticket 6</ticket>
        <ticket key="6-2">Ticket 7</ticket>
        <ticket key="6-3">Ticket 8</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="7">
        <ticket key="7-1">Ticket 7</ticket>
        <ticket key="7-2">Ticket 8</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="8">
        <ticket key="8-1">Ticket 8</ticket>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Desired result

```
<document>
<pages>
    <page key="1">
        <ticket key="1-1">Ticket 1</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-2">Ticket 2</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-3">Ticket 3</ticket>
        <ticket key="1-4">Ticket 4</ticket>
    </page>
    <page key="2">
        <ticket key="2-1">Ticket 5</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-2">Ticket 6</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-3">Ticket 7</ticket>
        <ticket key="2-4">Ticket 8</ticket>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a key here, not if you are using a constant value for the lookup. A simple variable will do

```
 <xsl:variable name="participants" select="//Participant" />
```

Then, to select the first participant for each page, do this (similar to one of your commented out lines)

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$participants[(position() mod $groupSize) = 1]" mode="page"/>
```

Then, to get the participants in a page do this...

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following::Participant[position() &lt; $groupSize]" mode="item">
```

Note the use of `following` instead of `following-sibling` because although you may have selected a participant from a variable (or key), when you use an axis operator like `following-sibling` it refers to the nodes in the actual document, not just the ones in the variable/keys. (`following-sibling` would only get the participants with the same parent as the one selected).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="participants" select="//Participant" />
<xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="4" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <pages>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$participants[(position() mod $groupSize) = 1]" mode="page"/>
        </pages>
    </document>
</xsl:template>

<!--Page-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="page">
    <xsl:variable name="PageNumber" select="position()" />
    <page key="{$PageNumber}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following::Participant[position() &lt; $groupSize]" mode="item">
            <xsl:with-param name="PageNumber" select="$PageNumber"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </page>
</xsl:template>
<!--Tickets-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:param name="PageNumber"/>
    <ticket key="{$PageNumber}-{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </ticket>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed, thanks!. I guess I was overthinking it and made it  more complicated then it actually was.